# Get which child of an optgroup has been selected

Tags: javascript, html, dom, optgroup

In JavaScript (please, NOT jQuery solutions) is it possible to get which child of an optgroup has been selected? I try to explain better. Given a select:

```
<select name="testSelect">
   <optgroup label="fruits">
      <option value="apples">Apples</option>
      <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
      <option value="pears">Pears</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="cars">
      <option value="ford">ford</option>
      <option value="toyota">toyota</option>
      <option value="ferrari">ferrari</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

I know I can get the index of the selected item, but it's not what I'm looking for because I will get 0 (apples), 1 (oranges), 2 (pears), 3 (ford), 4 (toyota), 5 (ferrari), while I want:

```
0: apples
1: oranges
2: pears

0: ford
1: toyota
2: ferrari
```

So, is there any way to get the index starting from a given optgroup?

(my question could really be no different, but 4 years in the current HTML/JS world is like a geological period, so I thought there was something new I hadn't discovered)

Comment: @DavidDomain: I red this before posting, the accepted answer dates back to 2013, I thought it's a lot of time in the HTML/JS current world

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this. What will you do with the index?

Comment: @nnnnnn: simply put: I'm editing the code of an ex-collegue who created a JS structure (an array of Objects) done in a particular way. There are new requirements but, before changing his structure, I wanted to try to get the index in a way "compatible" with his work   :-)